# Open Visio-File with Excel 2016 doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I have a small Excel-macro which opens a visio-file. With Excel 2010 everything worked fine. Now I've installed Office 2016 and tried the same excel-macro and it won't work.

There is no exception, but I see that my variable "VisioDoc" is empty.

Do you have any ideas where the Problem could be?

```
Sub cmdChooseFile_Click()

'...do something

Set VisioDoc = openDocument(filepath)
   If VisioDoc Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "boom, didn't work!", vbExclamation
      Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub

Private Function openDocument(docPath As String) As Visio.Document
    visioOpened = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Lade Visiodokument..."
    On Error Resume Next

    Set VisioApp = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")

    If VisioApp Is Nothing Then
        Set VisioApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
        VisioApp.Visible = False
        visioOpened = False
    End If

    Set openDocument = VisioApp.Documents.Open(docPath)
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Function
```

Comment: The line *On Error Resume Next* is suppressing the error message.  Trying removing it and running again.  Now you should have an error message that describes the problem.

Comment: Also, what version of Visio are you targeting here?

Comment: If I remove "On Error Resume Next" then the runtime error 429 occures: "Object creation failed".

Comment: I've tested the code with Excel 32 and 64bit, different language packs and it still won't work. anybod an idea?

Comment: No answer I'm afraid but this suggests there might be issues http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2015/12/01/supported-scenarios-of-multiple-office-products.aspx  For the record Excel 2016 to Visio 2016 does work ok.